# Automatically creating a OneToOneField when accessed

Tags: python, django, one-to-one, relation

I have two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # (...)
    settings = models.OneToOneField('Settings', null=True)
    # (...)

class Settings(model.Model):
    # (...)
```

Is there a way to create an instance of **Settings** whenever **Profile#settings** is accessed?

**UPDATE:** My main motivation for wanting this is that I already have the **Profile** model and I wanted the **Setting** relation to be lazily created when the user hits a point of the app that needs the **Profile#setting** instance, without caring about whether it is created or not.

**UPDATE:** @miki725 said below that this is handled by Django already. I tried the following:

```
class SettingsTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='felipe', email='something@aol.com')
        self.profile = Profile.objects.create(short_name='Felipe', name='Felipe',
            user=user)

    def test_settings(self):
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.profile.settings)
```

And I get this:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_settings (activity.tests.settings.SettingsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/activity/tests/settings.py", line 20, in test_settings
    self.assertIsNotNone(self.profile.settings)
AssertionError: unexpectedly None

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s
```

Comment: You may want to explain what do you mean by accessed. May be it can achieved by overriding `SettingsDoesNotExists` exception or `settings`  object manager.

Comment: @Rohan I want that when I do `profile.settings` I get a new **Settings** instance with all the default fields and the association back to the **Profile** instance in place.

Comment: can you sight an example?

Comment: Are you performing a saving action and you need a setting instance for your profile before it save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is automatically done by Django!

```
>>> p = Profile.objects.get(...)
>>> isinstance(p.settings, Settings)
True
```

**Update**

If you are getting None, that means the foreign key value in the `Profile` model is null since you allow null values `null=True`. In this case, you can't really do anything:

```
>>> p = Profile(settings=None, ...)
>>> p.save()
>>> p = Profile.objects.get(pk=p.pk)
>>> p.settings # the settings can't be anything because you never assigned them
None
```

If you need this for testing, then you will have to assign some settings value to the `Profile` instance:

```
class SettingsTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='felipe', email='something@aol.com')
        self.settings = Settings.objects.create(...)
        self.profile = Profile.objects.create(short_name='Felipe',
                                              name='Felipe',
                                              user=user,
                                              settings=self.settings)
```

By the way, starting with Django 1.5, you can configure your user model. Before you have to create a profile model which had to have a one-to-one key to the user model. Now that is no longer necessary. You can just add fields to the user model. You can read more about this in Django 1.5 release docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model).

**Update**

Now that your motivation is more clear, you can achieve that using this hackish method. I don't think it's the best approach but it should work:

```
Profile(models.Model):
    def get_default_settings(self):
        settings = Settings.objects.create(...)
        self.settings_id = settings.pk
        return settings

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        default = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if name == 'settings':
            if default is None:
                return self.get_default_settings()
            else:
                return default
        else:
            return default
```

Comment: For whatever reason it's **None** when creating a new **Profile**. See the update to my question.

Comment: Initially I did not notice the `null=True` part. I updated my answer.

Comment: You said: _"the settings can't be anything because you never assigned them"_, but that's the exact point of my question: can I make it so when I first access `p.settings`, a new instance of **Settings** with all the default values for the fields is created automatically?

Comment: My need is not for testing. I have the **Profile** model with tons of records, and I wanted to lazily create the **Settings** association when it is first accessed, without having to proactively create it.

Comment: refer to the updated answer. in the future please try to explain your motivations right away in the question to avoid the back-and-forth.

Comment: maybe you should correct the creation of user `User.objects.create_user(username='felipe', email='something@aol.com')`